# FRDM-KL46Z Internal Reference clock to 48 MHz?

Tags: c, embedded, arm, clock

I am working on IAR compiler for FRDM-KL46Z Platform.
I want to use Internal clock and set it to `48 MHz` (or as maximum as possible).
Till now I have done the following steps in the example `sysinit.c` file and function `sysinit()` provided.

```
#define NO_PLL_INIT

#if defined(NO_PLL_INIT)
mcg_clk_hz = 48000000;     // It only works on 21000000 Hz, otherwise I get garbage prints on UART0.
SIM_SOPT2 &= ~SIM_SOPT_PLLFLLSEL_MASK
uart0_clk_khz = (mcg_clk_hz) / 1000;
#else
....
```

In FEI mode, if I do FBI mode or BLPI mode, I get very less mcu clock.
I want the mcu clk to be as high as possible, in internal clock. (According to datasheet I think it is supported, but I don't know how?)

Can anyone please explain or any code reference, much obliged.

Comment: Additional info: this is a Freescale ARM Cortex M0+, KL4x family. And because this is such a hardware-specific question, you'll probably get better replies at https://community.freescale.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by doing this

```
#define NO_PLL_INIT

#if defined(NO_PLL_INIT)

MCG_C4 |= (MCG_C4_DRST_DRS(1) | MCG_C4_DMX32_MASK);
mcg_clk_hz = 48000000;

SIM_SOPT2 &= ~SIM_SOPT_PLLFLLSEL_MASK
uart0_clk_khz = (mcg_clk_hz) / 1000;

#else
....
```